# React BootStrap SplitButton

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, split-button

I have a snippet from a ReactComponent as follows:

```
<SplitButton bsStyle="info" bsSize="large" title="Main List">
    <MenuItem eventKey="1">Delete List</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem eventKey="2">Edit List Name</MenuItem>
</SplitButton>
```

I want to add a link to the "Main List" button, but currently I am still moving to that link on clicking the dropdown button of the `<SplitButton>` instead of the "Main List" title.

Where should I put the href tag to follow the link only when clicking the "Main List" button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add the `href` attribute to your `<SplitButton>`, like this:

```
<SplitButton href="http://google.com" bsStyle="info" bsSize="large" title="Main List" >
  <MenuItem eventKey="1">Delete List</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem eventKey="2">Edit List Name</MenuItem>
</SplitButton>
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/r4ueL3eu/)

There's a list of all properties for this particular component, [*here*](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#btn-dropdowns-props-split)